# Filtering list using linq and mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, filtering

Below is the code in question. I receive `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the `where` clause inside the Linq query. However, this only happens after it goes through and builds my viewpage.

Meaning: If I step through using debugger, I can watch it pull the correct order I am filtering for, go to the correct ViewPage, fill in the model/table with the correct filtered item, and THEN it comes back to my Controller and shows me the error.

```
public ActionResult OrderIndex(string searchBy, string search)
{
    var orders = repositoryOrder.GetOpenOrderList();

    if (Request.QueryString["FilterOrderNumber"] != null)
    {
        var ordersFiltered = from n in orders
            where n.OrderNumber.ToUpper().Contains(Request.QueryString["FilterOrderNumber"].ToUpper().ToString())
            select n;
        return View(ordersFiltered);
    }

    return View(orders);
}
```

Comment: where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.OrderNumber) && n.OrderNumber.ToUpper().Contains(Request.QueryString["FilterOrderNumber"].ToUpper().ToString())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its always better to manipulate your strings and other things outside the linq query ,

please refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

from the *readability point of view* also its not good ,

```
public ActionResult OrderIndex(string searchBy, string search)
{
    var orders = repositoryOrder.GetOpenOrderList();
    var orderNumber = Request.QueryString["FilterOrderNumber"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderNumber))
    {
        orderNumber = orderNumber.ToUpper();
        var ordersFiltered = from n in orders
            where n.OrderNumber.ToUpper().Contains(orderNumber)
            select n;
        return View(ordersFiltered);
    }

    return View(orders);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not being executed in your Action method because you don't have a `ToList` (or equivalent) added to your query. When your code returns, your query will be enumerated somewhere in your view and that's the point where the error occurs.

Try adding `ToList` to your query like this to force query execution in your action method:

```
var ordersFiltered = (from n in orders
                     where n.OrderNumber.ToUpper().Contains(Request.QueryString["FilterOrderNumber"].ToUpper().ToString())
                     select n).ToList();
```

What's going wrong is that a part of your `where` clause is `null`. This could be your query string parameter. Try moving the `Request.QueryString` part out of your query and into a temporary variable. If that's not the case make sure that your orders have an `OrderNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You both were right. Just separately.

This fixed my problem

```
var ordersFiltered = (from n in orders
                      where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.OrderNumber) && n.OrderNumber.ToUpper().Contains(Request.QueryString["FilterOrderNumber"].ToUpper().ToString())
                      select n);
```